# Groovy - Adding a line in middle of a file without modifying new line characters

Tags: groovy

I am using following groovy script to make changes in certain set of files (say Java files), and here I want to add package in file if not already present and the following code does the job (feel free to suggest optimizations here) but it updates the newline characters in that file which is something I would rather avoid, any advice?

```
void addIfRequired(def directory, def filePath) {
    def inputFile = new File(filePath)
    boolean containsPackage = false;
    List<String> lines = inputFile.readLines();
    for (def eachLine : lines) {
        eachLine = eachLine.trim();
        if (eachLine.startsWith("package ")) {
            containsPackage = true
            break
        } else if (eachLine.startsWith("import ")) {
            // Stop looking if we don't get package till import statement.
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!containsPackage) {
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        // The following API generates the package name
        def packageN = getPackage(inputFile, directory)
        boolean packageAdded = false;
        StringBuilder outputTxt = new StringBuilder();
        for (def line : lines) {
            if (!packageAdded && line.startsWith("import ")) {
                outputTxt.append("package " + packageN + ";" + lineSeparator)
                packageAdded = true;
            }
            outputTxt.append(line);
            outputTxt.append(lineSeparator);
        }
        inputFile.write(outputTxt.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these files created on some other OS than the one you are running script on? System prop for line separator is what you are adding after each line which can change the original line separator present in the file

Comment: @kunal I guess `lineSeparator` should be independent of OS. Picks up based on the system you are working on, right? Moreover, OP is rewriting the whole file from top to bottom.

Comment: @dmahapatro yes, if every line is rewritten with current OS line ending, which may be different from the OS those files were written on. In that case every line is updated, right? May be which is what OP is concerned about.

Comment: @kunal Correct you are. I was looking at the same thing and over read your comment. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your solution handles this case, but keep in mind this can get tricky for input files such as:

```
// Dangerous comment
// 
// import com.oldcompany.Bogus;

import com.foo.Example;

public MyClass {
}
```

However, both your solution (and mine) will fail if there is no import:

```
// random comment
// 

public MyClass {
}
```

Assuming there must be an import, here is one way to do it, using regular expressions:

```
def addIfRequired = { def directory, def filePath ->
    def inputFile = new File(filePath)
    boolean containsPackage = false;
    List<String> lines = inputFile.readLines();
    for (def eachLine : lines) {
        eachLine = eachLine.trim();
        if (eachLine.startsWith("package ")) {
            containsPackage = true
            break
        } else if (eachLine.startsWith("import ")) {
            // Stop looking if we don't get package till import statement.
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!containsPackage) {
        def lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator")
        // The following API generates the package name
        // def packageN = getPackage(inputFile, directory)
        def packageN = lineSeparator + "package com.abc.example;" + lineSeparator
        // TODO: potentially re-write the above code to use getText() so that 
        // we aren't reading the file twice. This could be tricky if the file is 
        // from an OS different from the OS used for this script ?

        String text = inputFile.getText()
        String replacement = packageN + "${lineSeparator}import"
        def regex = lineSeparator + /\s*import/
        String newText = text.replaceFirst(regex, replacement)

        inputFile.withWriter { def writer ->
            writer.write(newText)
        }        
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The predicate code (to determine if `package` is present) is unchanged. A drawback is that it reads the file twice. Re-writing the predicate code is left as an exercise to the reader.
- This code trims leading whitespace from the import statement. It is a bit messy, but I think it can be corrected, if that is a priority.
- To correct the "no import" problem, we probably just write the package on the first line.